# The Service 1 service on LocalComputer Started then Stoppped + SignalR Client In window Services

Tags: c#, signalr

I can't start signalR Client  Window service .its through exception that .

**The Service 1 service on Local-computer started then stopped. Some Service Stop Automatically If they're not in use by other service or program**

Note : my server is running on localhost and client also on local host

My code is here :

```
IDisposable SignalR { get; set; }
        private System.Diagnostics.EventLog eventLog1;
        private String UserName { get; set; }
        private IHubProxy HubProxy { get; set; }
        const string ServerURI = "http://*:8080/signalr";
        private HubConnection Connection { get; set; }

        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void ConnectAsync()
        {
            try
            {
            Connection = new HubConnection(ServerURI);
            HubProxy = Connection.CreateHubProxy("MyHub");
            //Handle incoming event from server: use Invoke to write to console from SignalR's thread


            HubProxy.On<string, string>("AddMessage", (name, message) =>
            {
                eventLog1.WriteEntry(string.Format("Incoming data: {0} {1}", name, message));
            });
            ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 10;

            eventLog1.WriteEntry("Connected");
            await Connection.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                eventLog1.WriteEntry(ex.ToString());
                //No connection: Don't enable Send button or show chat UI
                return;
            }

            //Activate UI
            eventLog1.WriteEntry("Connected to server at " + ServerURI + Environment.NewLine);
        }
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            string abd = "Tariq";

            ConnectAsync();
            HubProxy.Invoke("Send", UserName, abd);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `OnStart` code is assuming that the `async void` method has completed. It appears that `HubProxy.Invoke` is throwing an exception because it hasn't connected yet.

If this is confusing to you, I recommend reading my [`async` intro blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html), and also using my [`AsyncContextThread` type](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncContext) for asynchronous Win32 services. Then you can more properly avoid `async void`:

```
private AsyncContextThread _mainThread = new AsyncContextThread();

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
  _mainThread = new AsyncContextThread();
  _mainThread.Factory.Run(async () =>
  {
    string abd = "Tariq";
    await ConnectAsync();
    HubProxy.Invoke("Send", UserName, abd);
  });
}

private async Task ConnectAsync()
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: Couldn't found Assembly or reference  AsyncContextThread . what reference should I've to use ???

Comment: It's a NuGet package called `Nito.AsyncEx`.

Comment: Right-click your solution, select "Manage packages", and search for "AsyncEx".

Comment: Error 2 'SignalRClientWindowsServices.Service1.ConnectAsync()' does not return a Task and cannot be awaited. Consider changing it to return Task . .its give error on thats line.

 await ConnectAsync();
    HubProxy.Invoke("Send", UserName, abd);

Comment: hello Adam ,change Method name   private async void ConnectAsync() to    private async Task ConnectAsync() {} .